# std::set iterator with same key and different comparators

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, set, language-lawyer

While trying to solve a problem I started thinking about this - given a `user-defined class` and 2 `comparators` for it, lets say we have 2 sets `std::set<user_class,comparator_inc>` and `std::set<user_class,comparator_dec>` where the `comparators` sort by increasing and decreasing value on a value in the `user_class`(a simple `int` perhaps). Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::set;

struct A
{
    int val;
};
struct c_inc
{
    bool operator()(const A& first,const A& second) const
    {
        return first.val > second.val;
    }
};
struct c_dec
{
    bool operator()(const A& first,const A& second) const
    {
        return first.val < second.val;
    }
};

int main()
{
    set<A,c_inc> s1;
    set<A,c_dec> s2;

    auto x = s1.insert({1});
    cout << x.first->val << endl;

    x = s2.insert({1});
    x = s2.insert({0});

    cout << x.first->val << endl;   
}
```

My question is: Is it defined behavior to re-assign `x` to the output of `insert` into a `set` with same `Key` but different comparator? Is there a problem with this kind of use? Is it defined in the standard somewhere what it should be or is it implementation dependent?

Since the code compiles I think that the `return` type of `insert` in both cases is the same - is this assumption correct?

Comment: On your specific implementation, the return type is the same. It just so happens that the set's iterator inner class, in your C++ library, does not depend on the set's comparator class. But I cannot find anything in the standard that requires this to be the case.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I see - both gcc and clang seem to give same output in my very limited test case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's implementation dependent.

Conceptually the return type of `s1.insert` and `s2.insert` are different; especially they have different iterator types, i.e. `std::set<A,c_inc>::iterator` and `std::set<A,c_dec>::iterator`. And how the `std::set::iterator`'s type is defined is implementation-defined.

[[set.overview]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/set#overview-2)

> ```
> using iterator               = implementation-defined; // see [container.requirements]
> using const_iterator         = implementation-defined; // see [container.requirements]
> ```

Comment: @songyuanyao, if I may ask why `reverse_iterator` is **not** *implementation-defined*?

Comment: @codekaizer I think it's implementation-defined too. It's defined as `std::reverse_iterator<iterator>` so it depends on `iterator`.

Comment: @songyuanyao, thank you for pointing out it is also implementation-defined but depends on.

Comment: I think it would also make the code implementation-defined; since it can be determined from the iterator types whether or not they are assignable to each other

Comment: @M.M Is it possible that the iterator types are different but assignable?

Comment: @songyuanyao Yes

Comment: @M.M But standard doesn' say that; I mean, shouldn't such unmentioned things belong to undefined or unspecified?

Comment: The standard says that the types are implementation-defined.  Given any two types you can use other well-defined rules in the standard to decide if they are assignable or not

Comment: @M.M Got it. (padding)

Comment: Check out SCARY iterators.

Answer (score 3):

Technically speaking, you shouldn't rely on this.

> Since the code compiles I think that the return type of insert in both
>   cases is the same - is this assumption correct?

No, it is not. Imagine this simple example:

```
template<class T>
struct set {
   struct iterator { /*...*/ };
};
```

In this case `set<int>::iterator` is definitely different from `set<double>::iterator`.

The implementation is free to implement the iterator type as a free class though (since the iterator does not depend on the comparator), which seems to be the case in the major implementations, and is what's allowing your example.

Comment: I think you mean to point out that `set<A, C1>::iterator` is definitely different to `set<A, C2>::iterator` in this example  (and `set` should have two template parameters)

Comment: @M.M I think my example points that out. Perhaps I should've called it `foo`, it has no relation to std::set. I see the confusion.